# Sublime locks files so that git cannot unstash

Tags: git, locking, sublimetext3, git-bash, git-stash

I'm on Windows 10 Pro and using the Windows version of Git and Sublime (Build 3103). I installed git up so that I can use that before committing and pushing.

This is what happens when Sublime is open:

```
$ git up
Fetching origin
stashing 1 change
develop    up to date
master     up to date
unstashing
Unstashing failed!
```

Here's what git said:

> b'error: unable to create file app/scripts/controllers/products.controller.js (Permission denied)\n'

If I close Sublime there is no problem at all. I've tried running Git Bash both as user and as administrator, without any difference.

Also, this only occurs on the file that is the "active tab" in Sublime, not any other files that I have opened and made changes in.

Anyone knows what the problem might be?